# Вызов плагина в Pjax Yii2

Tags: yii2, form, tinymce, pjax

У меня подгружается форма через Pjax. В форме вызывается плагин для текстового редактора

```
echo $form->field($model, $element['table']['field'])->widget(TinyMce::className(), [
                                            'options' => ['rows' => 6],
                                            'language' => 'ru',
                                            'clientOptions' => [
                                                'plugins' => [
                                                    "advlist autolink lists link charmap print preview anchor",
                                                    "searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen",
                                                    "insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste"
                                                ],
                                                'toolbar' => "undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image"
                                            ]
                                        ]);
```

Но он не срабатывает. Что надо сделать, что бы он заработал? Спасибо

Comment: Добавьте вручную инициализацию tinyMce после события pjax:end в javascript

Comment: пробовал написать tinymce.init(), говорит "tinymce" undefindet

Comment: Посмотрите в папке виджета(я не знаю какой именно вы используете), может там есть Asset для загрузки tinymce, и во вьюхе сразу при загрузке регистрируйте его, чтобы он загружался

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте добавить в начале view страницы

```
\dosamigos\tinymce\TinyMceAsset::register($this);
```